# Need algorithm or solution to check if multiple range overlap

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need algorithm or solution to check if multiple range overlap in between with each other! This range can be dynamic. For example:

//Dynamic Range

```
var a = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6] ];
```

So, in above array given, first array value of "a" has 1 and 2 as values, here, 2 comes in 3rd array value [2,3] so this should give false and so on...

Language preferred: Javascript

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Algorithm recommendations are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use double `some` methods and then uses those start and end intervals to check of overlap.

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6]];

const overlap = arr.some(([sA, eA], i) => {
  return arr.slice(i + 1).some(([sB, eB]) => {
    return sB >= sA && sB <= eA || eB >= sA && eB <= eA ||
      sA >= sB && sA <= eB || eA >= sB && eA <= eB
  })
})

console.log(overlap)
```